# Android not allowing multi lines in `EditText` when filtering the emojis

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am not allowing any special chars and emojis using this extension function. Basically, this will not allow any emojis, symbols, and special characters other than what we pass in `allowedChars`.

```
fun EditText.filterEmojisAndDigits(allowedChars: String) {
    filters = arrayOf(InputFilter { source, _, _, _, _, _ ->
        source.filter {
            Character.getType(it) != Character.SURROGATE.toInt() &&
                    Character.getType(it) != Character.OTHER_SYMBOL.toInt() &&
                    allowedChars.contains(it, false)
        }
    })
}
```

This is I made the `EditText`

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/etAddComment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/dotted"
        android:gravity="center|start"
        android:hint="@string/enter_comments"
        android:digits="@string/supported_digits"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLength="950"
        android:maxLines="10"
        tools:text="Test data"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/dp_150"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp_10"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dp_10"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:textColorHint="@color/secondary_text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp_16" />
```

Where `supported_digits` are:

```
<string name="supported_digits">!"#$%&amp;'()*+,-./0123456789:;&lt;=&gt;?{|}~[\]^_`@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</string>
```

This is working fine but not allowing multiple lines.
Any idea how can we support multi-lines along with filtering emojis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added `\n` in the `supported_digits` then it worked.

i.e.,

```
<string name="supported_digits">!"#$%&amp;'()*+,-./0123456789:;&lt;=&gt;?{|}~[\]^_`@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n</string>
```